# $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $K$ if each element in $K$ is the limit of a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, cauchy-sequences

> Let $K$ be an ordered field containing the field of rationals
> $\mathbb{Q}$. Prove that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $K$ if and only if
> every element of $K$ is the limit of a Cauchy sequence in
> $\mathbb{Q}$.

Definition: $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $K$ if for each pair $x,y$ in $K$, $x<y$, there exists $z\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $x<z<y$.
The $\Leftarrow$ is trivial since for each $k\in K$, $k$ is the limit of a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{Q}$, so $k\in\mathbb{Q}\Rightarrow K=\mathbb{Q}$.
I'm stuck at $\Rightarrow$. For $k\in K$, I guess I have to construct a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{Q}$ that converges to $k$ by using the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $K$. But I don't know how to proceed it. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Alex. I am a bit suspicious of your proof of $\impliedby$. Am I reading correctly that you've proved that "if every element of $K$ is the limit of a Cauchy sequence in $\Bbb Q$, then $K = \Bbb Q$"? I don't think this is true - consider $\Bbb R$, for example.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Yes, that's what I did. Well, may be I'm wrong. How can I fix it?

Comment: As I say, it's not true. It's a much stronger conclusion than just "$\Bbb Q$ is dense in $K$", which should set off some alarm bells. Is your argument "if some element $k$ is a limit of a sequence of rationals, then $k$ must be rational"? That's not true!! Every real number can be written as a limit of a sequence of rationals, for example. To fix it you should argue that every open interval in $K$ must contain a rational. Can you think of any ways that the assumption about every element being a limit can help with that?

Comment: I thing $\mathbb Q$ is dense  in all real algebraic extension (necessary real because there are not order in $\mathbb C$) and even trascendental one, including $\mathbb R$ itself.

Comment: Your backwards direction should conclude that $K = $ the closure of $\Bbb Q$, not $\Bbb Q$ itself.  This is often written $\overline {\Bbb Q}$

Comment: Can someone write the proof for $\Leftarrow$ in the answering section below. I'm so confused. Thanks in advance

Comment: @AlexNguyen How would you show it for real numbers? The proof is essentially the same.

Comment: @Marco I haven't known the prove in case of real numbers. Could u show me? Thanks very much

Comment: As Izaak suggested you can prove that for any open (in the order topology) neightbourhood of a point $x \in K$ there is a rational, use the definition of limit and the fact that $q_n \to x$ to show it. (a neightbourhood $I_r(x)$ of a point $x$ can be thought as the set of all $y \in K$ such that  $|x-y|<r$)

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming the ordinate field has a metric structure endowed by its absolute value, i.e. the metric which generates the order topology.

Let $k \in K$. As $K$ is a field then
$$
k-\frac{1}{n} \in K
$$
By density there exists $q_n \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $k-\frac{1}{n} < q_n < k-\frac{1}{n+1}$

We have
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} q_n= k
$$
Indeed, for any $\epsilon \in K$, $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that, for each $n>N$ $$ |q_n-k|< \epsilon
$$
(see the edit below)

As convergent sequences are Cauchy that means that $k$ is the limit of a Cauchy sequence

**Edit:**

As said in the comments to show convergence we need to show that for any $h>0 \in K$ there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}/ \{0\}$ such that
$$
\frac{1}{n}<h
$$
(this is actually a characterization of the [Archimedean property for ordered fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property#Ordered_fields) ), but as $0 \in K$, by density there exists $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that
$$
0<q<h
$$
By the Archimedean property of $\mathbb{Q}$ there exists $n$ such that
$$
\frac{1}{n}<q<h
$$

Comment: Hi Marco. In the setting of an ordered field, I would assume that "$q_n$ is Cauchy" means "for any $\epsilon \in K$ with $\epsilon > 0$, there is some $N$ such that for $n, m \ge N$, we have $|q_n - q_m| < \epsilon$". Similarly I'd assume that "$q_n \to k$" means "for any $\epsilon \in K$ with $\epsilon > 0$, there is some $N$ such that for $n \ge N$ we have $|q_n - k| < \epsilon$", ie we work in the order topology. So to establish convergence of $q_n$ I think you need to show $K$ is Archimedean (which is true). The rest of your argument looks right to me!